# determine shortest distance between circle intersections

Tags: circles, trigonometry, discrete-mathematics

I have three circles positioned shown in the fig. Each of them has the same radius. I know the distance between each of them (A-B, B-C, A-C). My goal is to find the shortest path between B and C. The Path must always be in the range of any of the circle.(red line).

[image]

Math guys help.

Comment: This sounds a lot like a homework problem.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I found the distance between them using their coordinates, but don't know how to find the length of the arc between the circles.

Comment: Don't need the length of the arc, as pointed out by Hellin below, you just need to calculate the points of intersection and the distance between them.  Alternatively, you can find the angle CAB and use trig.

Comment: Is there a formula to calculate the points of intersection? I'm not good at math.

Comment: google or textbook

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand if you need some general algorithm (Then you need to check which one is intersecting which one... or not, or if you have more intersections, etc...)  or just a solution for this specific case.

For this case, it seems quite simple :

Compute intersections between circle A and circle B : it gives two points. Keep the one nearset to circle C (let's say I1).

Do the same for A and C, and keep nearest solution to circle B : I2.

Distance between I1 and I2 gives you the last portion of the red line you don't know.

Comment: there could be more than 3 circle in the space. I am kinda looking for general algorithm. and there is an arc between I1 and I2 (its not straight distance)

Comment: The arc is not the shortest distance within the circles, the straight line is.

Comment: As pointed by RishiG, some trig. should do the trick. However if you need arc circle, it means your fig. is wrong.